# Twilio's request parameter for speech

Tags: python, flask, twilio

[The documentation for the `<Gather>` tag (Python)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) says that:

> If you chose to gather digits from the caller, Twilio's request to
>   your application will include a **Digits** parameter containing which
>   numbers your caller entered during the .

But I can't find anywhere what is the parameter if the choice is to gather speech to be able to branch the call logic based on the speech sent by the user.

I tried **Speech** and **speech**, but didn't work.

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from TwilioPhoneCall import app
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Gather, Say
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse, Message


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def message():
    resp = VoiceResponse()

    gather = Gather(input='speech', timeout=3, hints='yes, no', action='/gather')
    gather.say('Hi, do you wanna go out tonight?'+
               ' Answer yes or no.')
    resp.append(gather)

    resp.redirect('/')

    return str(resp)

@app.route('/gather', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gather():
     resp = VoiceResponse()

     if 'Speech' in request.values:
         choice = request.values['Speech']

         if choice == 'yes':
             resp.say('Yay! See you later!')
             resp.sms('She replied yes!', to='myphonenumber')
             return str(resp)

         elif choice == 'no':
             resp.say('Oh... Ok.')
             resp.sms('She replied no.', to='myphonenumber')
             return str(resp)

          else:
              resp.say('Sorry, but the options are yes or no.')

    resp.redirect('/')

    return str(resp)
```

I already tried the exact same code with dtmf (Digits) and worked fine, my problem is with speech:

After the user speech his response the program will loop back to the first `gather.say` as if no input was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SpeechResult] is the return value you are looking for which contains the transcribed text.

Twilio also returns [Confidence] with a score between 0 and 1 (to 8 decimal places in my experience) for the likely indicated accuracy of the transcription.

Comment: Also your empty redirect after the gather will cause program loopback if no speech is detected. Timeout of 3 seconds is pretty low for gathering speech. I would either increase the timeout or add a URL to the redirect with a parameter to indicate no input was detected. Then include a condition for handling that parameter and prompting the user no input was detected.

Comment: Thanks @miknik! That did the trick! I just replaced were was Speech in the code for SpeechResult, but - it's relevant to mention: The speech regognition adds a final dot in the end of the input so to match I had to put 'yes.' and 'no.' instead of 'yes' and 'no' and then i got the desired result.

Comment: Yeah, Twilio seems pretty keen to add punctuation to transcription at every opportunity. "Hi there" always seems to get a comma inserted after Hi for instance, so if I'm parsing I strip all punctuation. Glad it's working for you now, hope she says "Yes" ;)

Answer (score 2):

The correct parameter name is `SpeechResult` not `Speech`.

```
   @app.route('/gather', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def gather():
         resp = VoiceResponse()

         if 'SpeechResult' in request.values:
             choice = request.values['SpeechResult']

             if choice == 'Yes.':
                 resp.say('Yay! See you later!')
                 resp.sms('She replied yes!', to='myphonenumber')
                 return str(resp)

             elif choice == 'No.':
                 resp.say('Oh... Ok.')
                 resp.sms('She replied no.', to='myphonenumber')
                 return str(resp)

              else:
                  resp.say('Sorry, but the options are yes or no.')

        resp.redirect('/')

        return str(resp)
```

Twilio blog: ***Introducing Speech Recognition*** https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/introducing-speech-recognition.html

Comment: I did that - as @miknik replied to, and it worked! Thanks for your answer!