# Twilio/Flask - store caller's speech to string variable

Tags: python, flask, twilio

My goal is to pay a simple message on Twilio that can capture the caller's reply. Base on the reply send the caller to next option. My challenge: how do I convert the callers speech into text? 
Following the examples here's the code to demonstrate this will work:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Gather, Say
from datetime import datetime
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test1", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test1():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    gather = Gather(input='speech',timeout=3,hints='cat, numbers, chuck')
    gather.say('Welcome to the fact hotline. Say cat numbers or chuck')
    response.append(gather)
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    resp.say('you said' + str(response))
    print(str(response))
    return str(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Gather hints= "cat, numbers, chuck" input="speech" timeout=3><Say>Welcome to the fact hotline. Say cat numbers or chuck</Say></Gather></Response>
```

If I said "chuck" I would like a variable = "chuck".
Can someone offer guidance?

Comment: The answer to my challenge was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748229/twilios-request-parameter-for-speech)